# Weird behavior in react dev tools for console.log

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, console.log, devtools

When I try and console.log somehthing, the console usually shows the name of the component and the line number. For some reason now it shows VM15:1. I've tried reinstalling react dev tools, and restarting my computer, and it doesn't seem to fix it. Restarting it a few weeks ago seemed to reset it, but for some reason the issue is back and restarting won't fix it now.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can avoid it?

[image]

Comment: This is my exact issue, though none of the solutions worked. The issue seems to be due to an extension I have enabled. After uninstalling the extension (Console Ninja) the issue is resolved! Just sucks because I like the extension.